# MyBatis - DB not recognizing Tablename

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

First I should say that I'm new to using MyBatis.

I am having a problem using MyBatis with any of my SQL statements running.
The SQL statements are being sent to the DB, but the tablenames aren't being recognized in the db.

For debugging purposes, I have a very simple table defined called 'clients'.
The database is PostgreSQL.
The same JDBC user is able to login with psql, and see and query the tables in a database, so I think that the problem should not be related to permissions.

For my simple test, I am running a very simple unparameterized query, but it fails:

```
select * from clients
```

I turned on logging in Postgresql and see the following.  The query statement is hitting the DB, but it doesn't seem to be able to recognize the table name.  I'm seeing basically the same error in the Java code too.

```
DEBUG:  StartTransaction
STATEMENT:  select * from clients
DEBUG:  name: unnamed; blockState:       DEFAULT; state: INPROGR, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0, nestlvl: 1, children: 
STATEMENT:  select * from clients
ERROR:  relation "clients" does not exist at character 15
```

To me this seems like a problem with either permissions or not using the dataSource correctly.  I think since the correct query statement is being sent that most of the 'mapper' wiring for myBatis is OK.

My environment is defined as follows:

```
<environments default="development">
    <environment id="development">
        <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
        <dataSource type="POOLED">
            <property name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/testdb" />
            <property name="username" value="topuser" />
            <property name="password" value="resupot" />
        </dataSource>
    </environment>
</environments>
```

'testdb' is where the table is located.  It seems like it is getting to the database (since  an entry is written to the postgres log) correctly but it's not looking in the testdb database.  I think this because I get a similar error when I issue this query statement in psql when not connected to the right database.

I also tried changing the query to use the schema name 'public', which is where the table is, but it fails in a similar way:

```
select * from public.clients
```

The Java code is just something like:

```
sqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SELECT_ENTRY);
```

In Java I tried to get at the dataSource in the sqlSessionTemplate to see if it is correctly configured prior to initiating the query, but information like the url and username are not available from the javax.sql.DataSource object to examine.

Tried typecasting it to org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource in order to get at the url configuration, as suggested somewhere online, but I just get typecast errors.

**Added Mapper information**

```
<mapper namespace="testClient">

  <resultMap id="result_Client" type="clientData">
      <result property="id" column="id" jdbcType="BIGINT" javaType="long"/>
      <result property="clientName" column="clientName" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="java.lang.String"/>
  </resultMap>

  <select id="selectEntries" resultMap="result_Client">
    select * from clients     
  </select>

</mapper>
```

**Added MyBatis Debug**

```
  2014-06-13 12:37:36,801  DEBUG [java.sql.Connection] [http-bio-8080-exec-25] ooo Connection Opened
  2014-06-13 12:37:36,801  DEBUG [java.sql.PreparedStatement] [http-bio-8080-exec-25] ==>  Executing: select * from clients
  2014-06-13 12:37:36,801  DEBUG [java.sql.PreparedStatement] [http-bio-8080-exec-25] ==> Parameters:
```

**Added the error seen in Java**

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation   "clients" does not exist
  Position: 15
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "clients" does not exist
  Position: 15
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:     relation "clients" does not exist
  Position: 15
```

Comment: If the database doesn't recognize the table name, then the table doesn't exist (in the selected database/schema) - it is beyond Java at this point and typecasting is not related.

Comment: What does your mapper file entry look like for `SELECT_ENTRY`? Also, you may want to enable `Mybatis` debug. See http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/logging.html.

Comment: @user2864740  I realize that.  I was attempting to see if the datasource was correctly configured.  Especially I wanted to see what the connection URL was that it had.

Comment: The point is: it's good to be *precise* with titles and questions.

Comment: @Ken I added the mapper definition.  I also had enabled Mybatis debugging, but I don't see anything there that helps.

Comment: Hmm... nothing stands out there in particular. Is there anything in the `Postgres` log near the debug you posted that says the DB it's in? Since it's saying the relation doesn't exist, I wonder if it actually connected to the `postgres` or `template1` DBs instead of `testdb` (even though you have that listed in the URL). You may want to grab the connection info out of the `SqlSession` object (IIRC, that is chained in the object hierarchy somehow, but I don't recall exactly how offhand) to see if it's indeed connecting to the DB you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks.  But I'm not seeing how to get to the SqlSession from the sqlSessionTemplate and even then I don't see from the docs that the SqlSession has the database name or other connection information available.  Also not seeing the database name show up in the postgres log -- maybe a problem?

Comment: Hmm... you could try setting debug on the `Postgres` `JDBC` driver and see if that yields anything else. You should be able to set the loglevel to 2 (`org.postgresql.Driver.DEBUG`) when creating the initial connection.

Comment: You may change postgres log format and add db name to each log entry. This will show which db you are connected to.